# How to make bold italics of a discord bot message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Well, I need to change the italics of the message to bold that the bot sends, it sounds simple. but I don't know how to do it.

Discord.js@12.2.0

```js
execute(message) {
  const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
  return message.channel.send('Check this site for a list of commands.');
}
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single * wrapped around the text. This is the usual convention of most italic text so keep track of it

```js
message.channel.send('*Check this site for a list of commands.*');
```

Here's a quick guide by discord I found on their markdown:

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-

Comment: Strange, when I wrote this, I got an error.. In any case, thank you very much

Comment: Even if it was incorrect it shouldn't output an error, its more likely you had the stars outside of the string